# how to 'clear' or drop an element in a Matlab structure

Tags: matlab

```
clear mice  %drops variable named mice
```

If I have

```
x.cat = 9; x.dog = 5
```

how can I `clear`  element `dog`?

(`clear x.dog` does not remove dog or even empty the contents.)

thanks

Comment: why vote this down? none of the related links to the side talk about this. And "Matlab help" doesn't refer to "rmfield" in the 'See Also' with respect to 'clear' ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [RMFIELD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rmfield.html):

```
xCleared = rmfield(x,'dog');
```

Answer (score 1):

use [`rmfield`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rmfield.html) to remove a specific field from a structure array, for example:

```
x = rmfield(x, 'dog')
```

if you just want to clear a value use:

```
x.dog=[];
```